# i need execute command after ssh connection, but have command sustitution

Tags: bash, ssh, posix

but needed execute $() in server,  it is running before ssh

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "${SSH_KEY}" "${HOST}" "$(command)"
```

this is a script that I need to run that code on the server

Comment: Do you really want `$( )` here? That'll run the command (on one computer or the other), and then try to execute its output as *another* command (on the remote computer).

Answer (score 1):

If you run that, it will execute whats inside of the **$()** before connecting to the server. Then it will send the result to be executed.

I think what you want is do this :

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "${SSH_KEY}" "${HOST}" 'command'
```

Where command might be something like :

```
ls -lh | grep someword
```

Let me know if I am correct.

Comment: Just use '$(command)' then. the single quotes will prevent your shell from interpolating the result